# Why getting Error ORA-00937

Tags: sql, oracle

> For each pilot who is certified for more than three aircraft, find the
>   aid and the maximum cruisingrange of the aircraft that he (or she) is
>   certified for.

I have four tables

FLIGHTS(**flno**:varchar, ffrom:varchar, fto:varchar, distance:integer, departs:date, Arrives:date);

AIRCRAFT(**aid**:varchar, aname:varchar, Cruisingrange:number);

EMPLOYEES(**eid**:varchar, Ename:varchar, Salary:number);

CERTIFIED (eid:varchar, aid:varchar);

My query:

```
SELECT aname, MAX(cruisingrange)
FROM   Aircraft 
WHERE aid IN(SELECT aid 
         FROM Certified
         WHERE eid = (SELECT eid
                      FROM Certified
                      GROUP BY eid
                      HAVING COUNT(eid) > 3) ) 
;
```

But it results in this error:

> ORA 00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Comment: Change 'WHERE eid = (' to 'WHERE eid IN ('

Comment: tnx for the repply . just changed it . but still getting the same error

Comment: Not a single one of the images you posted was necessary. Everything you included could have been done as text. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons NOT to post images unless your problem cannot be demonstrated in another way.

Comment: Welcome to so !

Comment: before the `;` you need `group by aname`  you have an aggregate max(cruisingrange) without a group by for aname.  All non-aggregated fields from the select must be listed in the group by.  some exclusions apply (see mySQL group by extensions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing group by in outer select.  All non-aggregates in a select statement must be listed in the group by.

```
SELECT aname, MAX(cruisingrange)
FROM   Aircraft 
WHERE aid IN(SELECT aid 
         FROM Certified
         WHERE eid in (SELECT eid
                      FROM Certified
                      GROUP BY eid
                      HAVING COUNT(eid) > 3) )
GROUP BY aname 
;
```

Note you have a group by on the inner most select; but you seem to be missing it 
on the outermost.

I also agree do you mean `in` or `equal` will more than one EID be in Certified  if so you likely need `in` vs `=`